# Property 'close' does not exist on type 'Application'

Tags: express, typescript, typescript-typings

I am importing expressjs like this:

```
import { Request, Response, Application, Router } from 'express';
const app: Application = require('express')();
```

and in typings.json:

```
 "express": "registry:npm/express#4.14.0+20160925001530",
```

when i type `app.close()` i get:

```
[ts] Property 'close' does not exist on type 'Application'.
```

- How can i solve this?
- Where can i report this? (if it is a bug)
- Am i the only one struggling alot with typescript typings?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The definition of Application provided does not have the method close...Server does and `(app:Application).listen` returns a Server.

```
start(){
    server = app.listen(options.port, function () {
        debug('Server listening on port ' + options.port)
    })
}
stop(){
    server.close();
}
```

You can report typings that are Definitely typed [here](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues). This is the package coming from [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/express).

Typescript is hard.